# generate black and white pdf using iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Can anyone help me to generate black and white pdf using iText. By default iText generate color pdf, now i want to generate black and white pdf. Can i..?

Comment: You can able to create the white colored by using

public static final BaseColor WHITE

and black by

public static final BaseColor BLACK.

Answer (score 0):

you can set brush color to black thus black text will appear . support for the same has been given by itextsharp on following URL

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/88/iTextSharp-Drawing-shapes-and-Graphics